# how do I map tensor using dictionary

Tags: python, pytorch

im trying to map tensor using dictionary but envir_with_agent[1,2] return tensor(4) instead 4 and dictionary cannot map it correctly min code is below

```
 envir_with_agent = b.mountain.clone()
envir_with_agent[b.position_agent[0], b.position_agent[1]] = 4
print(envir_with_agent[1,2])
print(b.dict_map_display[envir_with_agent[1,2]])
```

dict

```
        self.dict_map_display={ 
                            1:'.',
                            2:'o',
                            3:'O',
                            4:'A',
                            8:'E', 
                            9:'X'}
```

error

---

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 2 envir_with_agent[b.position_agent[0], b.position_agent[1]] = 4
> 3 print(envir_with_agent[1,2])
> ----> 4 print(b.dict_map_display[envir_with_agent[1,2]])
>
> KeyError: tensor(4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to first convert the scalar tensor to type `int` before using it as an index; like this:

```py
envir_with_agent = b.mountain.clone()
envir_with_agent[int(b.position_agent[0]), int(b.position_agent[1])] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the tensors to integers, **provided** `b.position_agent` is of *dtype* *long*:

```
envir_with_agent[b.position_agent[0].item(), b.position_agent[1].item()] = 4
```

Comment: thanks but your anwser will return agent position (1, 2) but i need to get dictionary value which is 4 and based on dict i should print  A as  4:A